# Cannot run setups from a vboxsvr mapped network drive on Windows within VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, windows

I'm trying to run an application setup by double-clicking the setup.exe from within Windows Explorer. The file is located on a mapped network drive, and I'm using Windows 7. This results in the following error message:

```
The specified path does not exist. Check the path, and then try again.
```

The workaround I found is to copy the installer to the main hard drive (c:) and run it from there; however, this is rather inconvenient. I have the impression that the problem only occurs with installers, as everything seemed to work fine with regular exe's.

Is there anyone who can explain this odd behavior?

**Update**: After some extended tests I noticed that the problem only occurs with a mapped drive of **VirtualBox**'s "shared folders" (cf. vboxsvr; VirtualBox v3.1.4). Mapping an SMB drive works fine.

**Update**: The same problem occurs on Windows Vista.

**Update**: Apparently, [this bug has already been reported in VirtualBox' bug tracker](http://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/5732).

Answer (score 4):

Yes I have faced the same problem like every one.

The most easy way to overcome this problem is to log in as an Administrator in the guest Windows OS. Here's a [tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/enable-the-hidden-administrator-account-on-windows-vista/) for enabling Administrator account in Windows 7

Another option is to disable the UAC (User Account Control). [Here's a link for disabling UAC](http://www.petri.co.il/disable-uac-in-windows-7.htm).
Disabling UAC is *dangerous* , it makes the job easier for malicious programs.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this issue by tweaking Local Group Policy:

Local Group Policy Editor (Run gpedit.msc) > Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options >

1. User Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for administrators... = Elevate without prompting
2. User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode = Disabled
3. User Account Control: Switch to the secure desktop when prompting for elevation = Disabled

Restart.

Credits: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/5732

Answer (score 1):

You either need to run it as administrator, or you need to add the network location to your Trusted Sites list in IE.

Answer (score 1):

As you already found out, the easiest way to overcome this is to use a network share path instead of a mapped network drive. Shared folders in VirtualBox appear as network shares in a network location called **VBoxSvr**. Type `\\VBoxSvr` in Explorer's address bar (or in Start Menu, or Run window), then press Enter. Now navigate to your desired shared folder/path and run your program.